# Does IPO inline functions?

Tags: c++, optimization, inline

I'm compiling on MSVC in Visual Studio 2012.
Even with maximum optimizations enabled, when I test my math library versus raw code I get 2 times faster code in the manually inlined raw code.My math functions are declared in a header and defined in a .cpp file.If I turn the .cpp file into an .inl file, I get performance identical to the raw code.So even with every possible optimization enabled, the compiler can't inline something that isn't defined in the header...I thought Interprocedural Optimization and link-time code generation would solve this, but I guess it doesn't.Absolutely nothing seems to get inlined in the non-raw case, it's over two times slower execution.Is there any way to get around this?Because most of my code is very performance intensive and I need to squeeze out maximum efficiency, but on the other hand I can't afford to have my entire library inlined in headers, the compilation would take hours.

Comment: What happens when you define them in the header? Do they inline? I suspect they won't.

Comment: they inline and the generated code becomes a little over 2 times faster

Comment: There's an option somewhere to optimize for speed or size, if you change it to speed do your results change?

Comment: You will need to look at the disassembly and look for clues (reasons) that prevent the compiler from automatically inlining these functions.